# Как загрузить файл с сервера библиотекой wininet?

Tags: c++

Всем привет! К примеру у меня есть сервер с файлом file.txt, в нём есть ссылка. Как мне можно загрузить файл с сервера на компьютер и вывести ту ссылку которая в ней? Знаю, что нужен GET запрос, но  можно пример с кодом, пожалуйста?

Comment: откуда вы знаете что нужен `POST`? не знаком с этой библиотекой, но обычно для загрузки с сервера используется `GET`, а `POST` - для загрузки на сервер

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/http-sessions

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch возможно GET, ошибся